# Difference between decimal number with comma and dot Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I should validate an input form testing if value is >= 0.

I get the value with jQuery and validate with a simple if statements. like this:

```
var value = $('#'+this.id).val();
    console.log("value is " + value );
    if(value >=0 ){
      console.log("true");
    }else{
      console.log("false");
    }
```

The problem raise when user inserts decimal number with comma or dot. 
If user insert `1.234` the result is `true` instead if inserts `1,234` the result is `false`

What is their difference?

I make a simple Fiddle for explain better the case.

http://jsfiddle.net/zzm8zno5/4/

I also verified the type of value; I tried to cast as number with `Number(value)` and nothing change

Sorry for my question, maybe is trivial but i don't understand why this happen

Comment: what will happen if user enters 1.234,55 or 1,234.55. Simple replacing the (.) will wield wrong results (wrong number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript does not recognise the comma as the decimal separator. You *have* to use a dot, `.`.

To do this you can use `replace()` to change the comma in the value. Also you need to use `parseFloat()` to compare the value, otherwise you're comparing a number (`0`) to a string (`'1.234'`). Try this:

```
var value = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', '.'));
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zzm8zno5/6/)

Finally, note the use of just `this` in the jQuery object. Since you already have a reference to the element you don't need to build another string selector. If you prefer you could shorten that further to just `this.value`

*Update*

Assuming that `1,234` is intended to mean `1234` and is not used as a decimal separator then you need to instead remove the `,` without replacement:

```
var value = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', ''));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Regards

Comment: When a user enters 1,234, he/she means 1234, not 1.234. This answer should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Rory about removing the comma (',') except that you need to replace it with dot ('.'). I believe what you want to happen is to get only the numbers, not replacing comma with dots.

```
1,234 = 1234 and not 1.234
```

use only this:

```
var value = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', ''));
```

Here's a [JSFiddel update](http://jsfiddle.net/p1r4ftzt/) from @rory's answer

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only knows 64bit double precision floating point variables.
Your comma is splitting the double to two decimals.

You need to stringreplace the input (, to .)